# Is this a fruiting or ornamental (flowering) tree?

Tags: identification, trees

Is this a fruit bearing tree or only ornamental?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks a lot like an apple tree, which would probably qualify as "fruit bearing" in the sense of your question.

Note that the distinction between "ornamental" and "fruit bearing" can be quite fuzzy - trees planted for their fruit can be stunningly beautiful when in bloom (ask every apple-producing region that has a thriving tourism business during blooming season!) and many plants chosen for their decorative appearance produce edible fruit (for example [flowering quinces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaenomeles) or [serviceberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelanchier)).

I suggest you wait until autumn to find out whether you like the fruit of your tree and until late winter, to give it a good pruning. It looks a bit overgrown and especially fruit bearing trees benefit from good pruning. Either educate yourself or find a good gardener to do it (and teach you, if possible). You might want to plan for an initial phase of getting the tree in shape over two or three years, then annual upkeep. I'd be wary of any gardener that wants to get it in shape with one drastic cutting session, but that's my personal approach.

Comment: I agree with Stephie (I'm more about quinces). Possibly in summer you could send us photos of leaves (close-up) and with few fruits (and maybe now you can also take a close-up photo of one flower), so that we can identify the species (and possibly the variety) of such plant.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I agree that an id is somewhat vague, but for quince I'd expect the blossoms to be more cupped and the leaves a bit more grown at the time of blooming. (I was wavering as well.) But time will tell for sure.